# Get-AzAutomationJob returns nothing when using managed identity for an automation account

Tags: azure, automation

I've given the automation account a system assigned managed identity. Successfully used these to set the context :

```
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
```

But when I use this inside the runbook to get the jobs :

```
Get-AzAutomationJob -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName -RunbookName $runbookName -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
```

it returns nothing. No error, so command must execute, but doesn't return any results.
What I noticed is that the context which returns when connecting with the managed identity, doesn't have values for Name and Subscription. It only has values for Account, Environment and Tenant. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a short test with your commands in the portal powershell and used 'Get-AzAutomationJob' with two runbooks. One of them has the status set to 'Published' and the other to 'New'. The new one has no prior jobs that ran.

[image]

```
Get-AzAutomationJob -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName  -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName -RunbookName "shutdown" -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
```

yields the result:

```
ResourceGroupName      : Dev-Portal-01_group
AutomationAccountName  : ls-automation
JobId                  : 06f06c17-77fb-4565-9ad4-da9ca0e5a4ea
CreationTime           : 10/26/2022 3:00:20 PM +00:00
Status                 : Completed
StatusDetails          : 
StartTime              : 10/26/2022 3:00:28 PM +00:00
EndTime                : 10/26/2022 3:00:32 PM +00:00
Exception              : 
LastModifiedTime       : 10/26/2022 3:00:32 PM +00:00
LastStatusModifiedTime : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM +00:00
JobParameters          : {}
RunbookName            : shutdown
HybridWorker           : 
StartedBy              :
```

and several more showing in the portal.
[image]

whereas

```
Get-AzAutomationJob -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName  -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName -RunbookName "provision-portal" -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
```

Gives back nothing.

After creating a simple scheduled job in the 'provision-portal' runbook I received output when running the same command again:

```
ResourceGroupName      : Dev-Portal-01_group
AutomationAccountName  : ls-automation
JobId                  : 21ff3540-9843-4ccc-8775-12ffa12c128b
CreationTime           : 10/27/2022 7:07:01 AM +00:00
Status                 : Completed
StatusDetails          : 
StartTime              : 10/27/2022 7:07:16 AM +00:00
EndTime                : 10/27/2022 7:07:20 AM +00:00
Exception              : 
LastModifiedTime       : 10/27/2022 7:07:20 AM +00:00
LastStatusModifiedTime : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM +00:00
JobParameters          : {}
RunbookName            : provision-portal
HybridWorker           : 
StartedBy              :
```

Can you check the Authoring status and see if it is published and if any jobs are running or ran?

Kind regards

Comment: The runbook is published. But on your screenshot I noticed that your runbooks are version 7.1, while mine is 5.1. I'm starting to get more and more convinced that the problem is with the context and the empty value for "subscription". Could the older powershell version lead to this problem?

Comment: Updated the answer after some further investigation from my side

Comment: The runbook has been running for two years. But the certificate expired and now I'm trying to use a managed identity for the automation account since the certificate method will soon be deprecated. So the runbook is published and has jobs. Is there a way to troubleshoot why ```Connect-AzAccount -Identity``` doesn't return a value for "subscription"?

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem turned out quite trivial. I had to give permissions for the subscription to the managed identity. Even though I'm not using this identity to access any resources, it still needs permissions to read the subscription data. Unlike the Run As account which doesn't need any permissions. So "problem" solved. Thank you for your time and desire to help!